# How to use two <header> tags on one page?

Tags: html, css, browser, header, nav

There are two sections on this page, let's say Content A and Content B.

I'd like both Content A and Content B titles in their own horizontal bars that span the entire width of the page.

I've tried nav tags, ran into problems.

Now I'm trying a header tag. It works fine for the first one, but the second one ends up overlapping other text.

I've tried setting the css of the second one to display inline block, added padding, added margins, nothing seems to work. It is as if it is fixed and I don't have anything set so that it's fixed.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can fix this? 
OR 
Other recommendations as to the best way to set up two simple browser-wide bars that have a title in them?

Comment: Hi, took one of the suggestions but ran into problems...


All I want to do is create two centered browser wide title bars.

I used the following code in the html:

INFORMATION 1 and INFORMATION 2

The CSS is : .information1 { width: 100%; background-color: blue; vertical-align: center; text-align: center; color: white; }

The results are only showing up locally but not when I upload it to the server. The colors don't show up, the text is showing as black, and it's everything aligns to the left.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use h1,h2,h3 or you can give the headers ID or class like this

```
<h1 id=secA><h1>
<h1 id=secB><h1>
```

then use css to modify them to your needs

EDIT 1:

I don't know what you are trying to do but I hope this gives you some ideas

https://jsfiddle.net/tv1xhzum/

Comment: hi, I tried this and then added this css styling: .firstbar{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
} and for some reason nothing is showing up. All that shows up is the title of the bar and it's going flush left and absolutely no colors are showing. Any idea why that would be?

Comment: Hi, took one of the suggestions but ran into problems...


All I want to do is create two centered browser wide title bars.

I used the following code in the html:

INFORMATION 1 and INFORMATION 2

The CSS is : .information1 { width: 100%; background-color: blue; vertical-align: center; text-align: center; color: white; }

The results are only showing up locally but not when I upload it to the server. The colors don't show up, the text is showing as black, and it's everything aligns to the left.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?

Comment: Its hard for me to understand what you are trying to accomplish with just words can you draw a diagram in paint or maybe post codes here?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I'm not sure how to insert a painted picture here?  I think my problems very easy but I have struggled with it for days. I literally just want to create two full-width navigation type bars that have a title in each. But I don't want to label them as nav bars, because my code doesn't seem to work with nav tags.  Above I shared the HTML and the CSS I used and the problem is none of the styling is showing up. Are there any easy ways to get two browser wide bars on a page? So frustrated =(( At this one problem for days.

Comment: I feel like your css is not linked to your html page when you say any of the css styling is not applied and everything is aligned to left. just make sure everything is set.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
  <header>
    <h1 id="ex01">example01</h1>
    <h3 id="ex02">example02</h3>
    
  </header>
```

Comment: hi will this technique work if I want both of the titles to be an h2?

Comment: Hi, took one of the suggestions but ran into problems...


All I want to do is create two centered browser wide title bars.

I used the following code in the html:

INFORMATION 1 and INFORMATION 2

The CSS is : .information1 { width: 100%; background-color: blue; vertical-align: center; text-align: center; color: white; }

The results are only showing up locally but not when I upload it to the server. The colors don't show up, the text is showing as black, and it's everything aligns to the left.

Can anyone spot what I'm missing?